# importing one java script file to another file error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 files one HTML, 2 javascript files named app.js and customer .js

I have an HTML page on which I have written this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    hello
    <script src="app.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I just loaded app.js into this page

app.js contains this

```
import {person} from "./customer";
console.log("helllo");
```

and in customer.js i have this

```
const person={
    name:"hello"
}

export default person;
```

I am getting an import error the error shows

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/customer net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I am new to web development, please help me.

Comment: What do you use for routing?

Comment: Remove the "." from your import statement, and add the extension. Try `import {person} from "/customer.js";` You're relying on the browser, not a Javascript bundler.

Comment: Please share your directory structure and what server you are using.

Comment: @TJBlackman I just changed in that way and this new error pops up
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/customer.js' does not provide an export named 'person'

Comment: Look at the difference in `export` and `export default`. Remove the curly braces if you want to keep using export default. `import person from "/customer.js`

Comment: @Danial Can you explain what do you mean by routing?

Comment: @TJBlackman that worked thank you, but when I am trying to write a function in app.js and using the function in the above HTML file it shows an error, whereas if I remove the import statement from app.js the function worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the way you are importing it is wrong.

Let me explain. First of all, I can see that you are default exporting the module or whatever. In that case, you don't need those curly brackets.

```js
import person from "./customer.js";
```

Second, just make sure that in your `package.json` you have `"type"` set to `"module"` just like this

```
"type": "module",
```

Third, if you are using VSCode, then you can right-click on your `customer.js` file and click on `copy relative path` to get its relative path from your project.

Summary:

1. Correct your import statement
2. Check if package.json is correct
3. Copy relative path using VSCode

Hope this helps to solve your query!

Answer (score -1):

if you got a:

```
1) index.html:1 Access to script at 'file://$PATH'  from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:  Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes:  http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

2) GET file://$PATH net::ERR_FAILED
```

You need to use local-web-server, for example Live Server in VS Code.